# How to reopen a question?

Tags: discussion

I've come to notice that in SO there are two questions that were closed:

1. [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)
2. [Looking for C# HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-sharp-html-parser)

They closed each other saying that the other is the duplicate oO, how can one be opened?

Comment: Answer to "What is the best" type of question is usually equally correct. Such question usually will be closed as not constructive with the current rule.

Comment: Question 2 is closed as a dupe of question 1, which is closed as not constructive. I don't think it stands much of a chance of being reopened.

Answer (score 9):

The closed message on [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56107/961353) clearly states that it has been closed as [Not Constructive](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close), not as a duplicate. Since it has been locked, it cannot be reopened by most users.

It can be unlocked and reopened by a moderator, but this is unlikely as the question isn't within the scope of the site.

Comment: It can be reopened, but would need to be unlocked first.

Comment: It is locked, but it can be unlocked and reopen by mod. (But it won't be unlocked and reopened in the near future).

Answer (score 7):

The questions have been merged, not only closed as duplicate. There is no way to reopen a question that was merged into another one.

The target of the merge is closed as not constructive and has also been locked by a moderator. There is no way for a regular user to reopen it, you'll have to convice a moderator to do it.

If you think this question should be reopened, make your case here on meta why it should be reopened. But I wouldn't give it a good chance of being reopened. This question has the "historical significance" lock, which means it was a nice question in its time, but it doesn't fit to the rules of the site now.